# Cabinet hinge broke, what are my options?

Tags: replacement, cabinets, hinges

One of my kitchen cabinet's hinges broke. Luckily I found a replacement part on the original manufacturer's [website](http://www.qmreplacements.com/hinges/) (#50 90-degree hinge).

[image: Quaker Maid #50 90-degree hinge, closed]
[image: Quaker Maid #50 90-degree hinge, open]

However it's $33 and not the exact same dimensions, so I'd need to drill out the hole to make it larger.

Should I just buy them, or are there other options that might be better? Perhaps different hinges, or an alternate seller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove one and see if you can get a part number and manufacturer name.  That will narrow your search.  Usually companies like Rockler (who sells hardware for cabinets) have a wider choice available than a big box store.

Comment: Does the OP have to replace *both* hinges although only one broke?